# Passing this by value

Tags: c++, this

Silly question: what is the best way to pass this by value?

Background: Let's use cars and car options. I used to have constructors such as Ford(FordOptions), Honda(HondaOptions). All cars derive from Car, all options from CarOptions. I used to have a car factory that gets passed a pointer to a CarOption, checks the type, produces the appropriate car, and returns a pointer to a generic Car.

I have now changed this so that CarOption has a virtual ProduceCar returning a Car, and every individual car option implements its particular production. So when I get a generic pointer to a car option, I just call CarOptions.ProduceCar and get a generic pointer to a car.

This is all fine, except in the implementation for say FordOption.ProduceCar I need to pass the FordOption instance to the Ford constructor. I can do this by passing "this" and changing the constructur for Ford to accept a pointer to FordOptions instead of FordOptions. However, I'd like it to take FordOptions by value, or at least by reference, but struggle to do so.

Long question for a simple answer I bet. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, could you just post a simple example?

Comment: New edit makes answers seem incorrect. The OP wants to know how to pass the current object (pointed to by `this`), not how to pass the `this` pointer.

Comment: It's not a silly question, it's just a beginner's question.  There's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to dereference the `this` pointer... And depending on the called method, you pass a reference (as in the example), or by value

```
Ford::Ford(const FordOption &o) {}

Ford FordOption::produceCar() {
   return Ford(*this); // <-- Dereference this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a regular old pointer. So `*this` produces a reference to the object `this` points to, which can then be passed however you like.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to path `this` by value or reference, just use `*this`:

```
return new Ford(*this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to dereference the 'this' pointer. To do so, send *this to your contsructor.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a CarOption& which you believe is in fact a FordOption& ? Sounds like a job for the `dynamic_cast` operator.